# How to get all your watch history from youtube?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, history

So I want to create a program to get my entire watch history and put it into a list format (excel or html list) of all the videos from my watch history with their titles and their links.

I'm a novice though so I might have to pay someone else to do it, but I want to know if this is even possible and how to accomplish it in case I want to try it on my own.

https://google-developers.appspot.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_watch_history?hl=ar-SA

The API for v2.0 lists how to do it, but I'm not sure if that works for 3.0 since 2.0 has been deprecated. Any help please? thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know about "a program." It sounds like they no longer have an API for it. But you can partially automate it via the javascript console. The following instructions apply since youtube changed to material design and the history page uses infinite scrolling.

1. Go to https://www.youtube.com/feed/history in Google Chrome and open the javascript console. (Other browsers should work as well but there may be slight differences.)
2. In the javascript console you can automate scrolling down by entering `window.scrollBy(0, 100000)`. I haven't tried it but you should be able to do this repeatedly with something like `window.setInterval(() => window.scrollBy(0, 100000), 5000)`. That should cause a scroll-down every 5000ms (5 seconds); depending on your computer's speed you can tweak that number. 100000 is the number of pixels to scroll down. (It won't scroll past the end of the page, but hitting the end of the page causes it to load more and expand the page.)
3. Once the page has scrolled far enough, enter `console.clear(); document.querySelectorAll('h3 a').forEach(x => console.log(x.innerText))`. Based on the current page markup, this will log all the video titles (and a few other lines). (It will clear the console first.) NOTE: the `h3 a` part is subject to change. It means "all anchor tags that are inside a level-3 heading tag." Also, this line can be tweaked to get things besides titles.
4. Right-click in the console and in the context menu click `Save as...` to export what was just printed to a text file.

Comment: I tried it just now and it worked well, but I do not know how to stop the script in firefox once it reaches the bottom. I don't need to save it , i just want to now go through it myself.

Answer (score 1):

[Channels->list method](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) will return the [playlistId for the watch history](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.watchHistory).

Then you need to call [playlistItems->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) with that playlistID.